# How to start MongoDB Sharding on Reboot in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 shard and 3 Config server on Linux Ubuntu Instance. On system Reboot MongoDB database engine started automatically but Shard doesn't. 
can you please help me to make it start automatically in server startup? what action should be taken.

**For example, i used below command to setup config**

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet c0 --port 26050 --logpath /data/db/log.c0 --logappend --dbpath /data/db/c0 --fork --bind_ip_all
```

**For Shard,**

```
mongod --shardsvr --replSet s1 --dbpath /data/s1 --logpath /data/s1/log.s1 --port 27000 --fork --logappend --bind_ip_all
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with the startup script on Linux.
I just need to initialize all services, Mongo shard, Config and Router need to be configured again.

as above,

```
mongod --configsvr --replSet c0 --port 26050 --logpath /data/db/log.c0 --logappend --dbpath /data/db/c0 --fork --bind_ip_all

mongod --shardsvr --replSet s1 --dbpath /data/s1 --logpath /data/s1/log.s1 --port 27000 --fork --logappend --bind_ip_all
```